# PHP multi-server sessions

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, multiserver

I have a PHP system that i'd like to port to be on more than one server if the need arises. Currently I store the user's current session information just in the default manner PHP does (assuming in memory). Can I get an example of what I need to put in a table in my MySQL database as well as some example of implementation?

Comment: have an idea of any specific functions to look at for this?

Comment: The one I hyperlinked above is a good start - try that?

Answer (score 1):

The default session storage system is actually on the file system. Some system caching may be used to pull it from memory.

Now in order to go into a multi-server setup, your servers need to basically share nothing with each other. To that goal, sessions need to be stored outside of the server they are created and accessed on.

Storing sessions in the database is one option, but it increases the load on your database and you have to be careful with locking in some cases. Default session handling has locking which allows only one thread to access a given session at a time, a database handler may not do that. If you are only reading session data, this is likely not going to be a problem, but if you are changing it, it could be.

The memcached extensions allow for session data replication to memcached nodes. I prefer this route as it allows you to keep sessions in memory and avoids adding extra db load (which is often more difficult to scale)